# Is there a way to summarise if column value is x?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a `data.frame` which displays the average time an individual displays a behaviour.

I have been using `group_by` and `summarise` to calculate the averages across groups. But the output is many rows down. See an example using the iris dataset...

```
data(iris)

x <- iris %>% 
     group_by(Species, Petal.Length) %>% 
     summarise(mean(Sepal.Length))
```

I would like to get an output that has, for this example, one row per 'Species' and a column of averages per 'Petal.Length'.

I have resorted to creating multiple outputs and then using `left_join` to combine them into the desired `data.frame`. See example below...

```
a <- iris %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>%
 filter(Petal.Length == 0.1) %>% 
 summarise(mean(Sepal.Length))

b <- iris %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>%
 filter(Petal.Length == 0.2) %>% 
 summarise(mean(Sepal.Length))

left_join(a, b)
```

However, doing this twelve or more times at a time is tedious and I am sure there must be an easy way to get the `mean(Sepal.Length)` for the 'Petal.Length' 0.1, and 0.2, and 0.3 (etc) in the one output.

n.b. in my data `Petal.Length` would actually be characters that represent behaviours and `Sepal.Length` would be the duration of time

Comment: Can you please show the desired output for this example? It's hard to understand because there are no rows where `Petal.Length == 0.1` is TRUE. It sounds like you should just use your `x` and then `pivot_wider` with `tidyr`.

Comment: Thank you that is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

mutate(iris, Petal.Length_discrete = cut(Petal.Length, 5)) %>% 
  group_by(Species, Petal.Length_discrete) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Sepal.Length))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Species'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    Petal.Length_discrete `mean(Sepal.Length)`
#>   <fct>      <fct>                                <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     (0.994,2.18]                          5.01
#> 2 versicolor (2.18,3.36]                           5   
#> 3 versicolor (3.36,4.54]                           5.81
#> 4 versicolor (4.54,5.72]                           6.43
#> 5 virginica  (3.36,4.54]                           4.9 
#> 6 virginica  (4.54,5.72]                           6.32
#> 7 virginica  (5.72,6.91]                           7.25

iris %>% 
  group_split(Species, Petal.Length) %>% 
  map(~ summarise(.x, mean(Sepal.Length))) %>% 
  head(3)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   `mean(Sepal.Length)`
#>                  <dbl>
#> 1                  4.6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   `mean(Sepal.Length)`
#>                  <dbl>
#> 1                  4.3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   `mean(Sepal.Length)`
#>                  <dbl>
#> 1                  5.4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>